# Why is atropine a CNS stimulant, although it blocks the muscarinic receptors in the brain?

Tags: neuroscience, pharmacology, psychoneuropharmacology

I know that atropine is a muscarinic  antagonist, so why does atropine have excitatory actions on the brain while it is blocking muscarinic receptors?

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer**
Atropine inhibits an inhibitor and hence its effects are excitatory.

**Background**
According to the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muscarinic_acetylcholine_receptor_M2) on muscarine M<sub>2</sub> receptor:

> M<sub>2</sub> muscarinic receptors act via a G<sub>i</sub> type receptor, which causes a
>   decrease in cAMP in the cell, generally leading to **inhibitory-type**
>   effects.

Atropine is an antimuscarinic (anticholinergic) drug.According to the wiki page on atropine:

> [R]eactions to atropine include ventricular fibrillation, supraventricular or ventricular tachycardia, dizziness, nausea, blurred vision, loss of balance, dilated pupils, photophobia, dry mouth and potentially extreme confusion, deliriant hallucinations, and **excitation** especially among the elderly.

So atropine blocks inhibitory muscarinic receptors, and hence causes excitation.

Comment: But the brain has M1 receptors which work with all the three Gq, Gs, Gi proteins! (The question has been corrected, pardon.)